# Azure python sdk service bus receive message

Tags: python-3.x, azureservicebus, azure-python-sdk

I am a bit confused about the azure python servicebus.

I have a servicebus TOPIC and SUBSCRIPTION which listen to specific messages, I have the code to receive those messages which then they will be processed by aws comprehend.

Following Microsoft documentation, the basic code to receive the message work and I am able to print it, but when I integrate the same logic with comprehend it fails.

Here is the example, this is the bit of code from Microsoft documentation:

```
with servicebus_client:
    # get the Queue Receiver object for the queue
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
    with receiver:
        for msg in receiver:
            print("Received: " + str(msg))
            # complete the message so that the message is removed from the queue
            receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

and the output is this

```
{"ModuleId":"123458", "Text":"This is amazing."}
Receive is done.
```

My first thought was that the message received, was a Json object. so I started writing the code to read data from a json outputs as follow:

```
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)
with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(
        topic_name=TOPIC_NAME,
        subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
    )
    with receiver:
        received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
        for msg in received_msgs:
            # print(str(msg))
            message = json.dumps(msg)
            text = message['Text']

            #passing the text to comprehend
            result_json= json.dumps(comprehend.detect_sentiment(Text=text, LanguageCode='en'), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
            result = json.loads(result_json) # converting json to python dictionary

            #extracting the sentiment value 
            sentiment = result["Sentiment"]

            #extracting the sentiment score
            if sentiment == "POSITIVE":
                value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Positive"] * 100,2)

            elif sentiment == "NEGATIVE":
                value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Negative"] * 100,2)

            elif sentiment == "NEUTRAL":
                value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Neutral"] * 100,2)
                
            elif sentiment == "MIXED":
                value = round(result["SentimentScore"]["Mixed"] * 100,2)

            #store the text, sentiment and value in a dictionary and convert it tp JSON
            output={'Text':text,'Sentiment':sentiment, 'Value':value}
            output_json = json.dumps(output)

            print('Text: ',text,'\nSentiment: ',sentiment,'\nValue: ', value)

            print('In JSON format\n',output_json)

            receiver.complete_message(msg)

print("Receive is done.")
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type ServiceBusReceivedMessage is not JSON serializable
```

Did this ever happened to anybody who can help me to understand what is the type of servicebus that is coming back from the receive?

Thank you so much everyone

Answer (score 1):

> Did this ever happened to anybody who can help me to understand what
> is the type of servicebus that is coming back from the receive?

The type of the received message is [`ServiceBusReceivedMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage?view=azure-python) which is derived from [`ServiceBusMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-python). The contents of the message can be fetched from its `body` property.

Can you please try something like:

```
message = json.dumps(msg.body)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. It did work. I just had to convert the msg to a str and I was able to receive the message.